# Android app crashing in onActivityResult method

Tags: java, android, crash

My android app is crashing in case 2 and case 3 don't work(don't take picture from camera). Case 0 and Case 1 works well.

onClick method:

```
           public void onClick(View v) {
                if(position == 0 && menuID == mFrameID1)
                {
                    Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(pickPhoto , 1);//pick photo from gallery
                }
                else if(position == 1 && menuID == mFrameID1)
                {
                    Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);//capture from camera
                }
               else if(position == 0 && menuID == mFrameID2)
                {
                    Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(pickPhoto , 2);//pick photo from gallery
                }
                else if(position == 1 && menuID == mFrameID2)
                {
                    Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(takePicture, 3);//capture from camera
                }
        }
```

onActivityResult method

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    switch(requestCode) {
        case 0:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) imageReturnedIntent.getExtras().get("data");
                mPhotoConteiner2.setImageBitmap(photo);
            }

            break;
        case 1:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                mPhotoConteiner2.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) imageReturnedIntent.getExtras().get("data");
                mPhotoConteiner1.setImageBitmap(photo);
            }

            break;
        case 3:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                mPhotoConteiner1.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Its crashing at line

```
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) imageReturnedIntent.getExtras().get("data");
```

in case 2

Sorry for that kind question, im newbie to android programming.
And thx for help.

Comment: you mixed 2 and 3. it's 3 and 2.

Comment: Yes, thx. I found this too :D

Comment: that would have been obvious if you had used constants with explicit names instead of `0, 1, 2, 3`

Answer (score 0):

Oh, the problem was that when I'm wrote code for case 2 and case 3 in wrong places. I should write case2 code in case3 and case3 in case2.